# Printing from Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-office-2013

when I try to print some documents downloaded from email I get a message that says "print from apps only." What does that mean? What do I need to do to print the document.

Comment: See here [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/winows-81-not-finding-wireless-printer-says-can/b52e78c6-dd56-4cec-9777-288aaf298529). It sounds like you just need to tell it to print to an actual printer though rather than the default Windows Printer that may be set to a virtual printer, etc. and not something that's physical.